# "PyTorch Conv2d error: Expected 3 channels, got 128 for [1, 128, 128, 3]. Help needed!"

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am encountering an issue while working with a PyTorch convolutional neural network. The error message I'm receiving is:

Given groups=1, weight of size [8, 3, 5, 5], expected input[1, 128, 128, 3] to have 3 channels, but got 128 channels instead

Context:

Model Architecture:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        self.cnn_model = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 3, out_channels = 8, kernel_size = 5),
        nn.Tanh(),
        nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size = 3, stride = 5),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 8, out_channels = 16, kernel_size = 5),
        nn.Tanh(),
        nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size = 2, stride = 5))
        
        self.fc_model = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(in_features = 256, out_features = 120),
        nn.Tanh(),
        nn.Linear(in_features = 120, out_features = 84),
        nn.Tanh(),
        nn.Linear(in_features = 84, out_features = 1))
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.cnn_model(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.fc_model(x)
        x = F.sigmoid(x)
        
        return x
```

Data Loading:

```
class MRI(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        # Load images and labels
        tumor = []
        path_tumor = '/kaggle/input/brain-tumor/Dataset/Yes_Data/*.jpg'
        for f in glob.iglob(path_tumor):
            img = cv2.imread(f)
            img = cv2.resize(img, (128, 128), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            tumor.append(img)

        healthy = []
        path_healthy = '/kaggle/input/brain-tumor/Dataset/No_data/*.jpg'
        for f in glob.iglob(path_healthy):
            img = cv2.imread(f)
            img = cv2.resize(img, (128, 128), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            healthy.append(img)

        # Convert lists to numpy arrays
        healthy = np.array(healthy)
        tumor = np.array(tumor)
        
        # Create labels
        tumor_label = np.ones(tumor.shape[0], dtype=np.float32)
        healthy_label = np.zeros(healthy.shape[0], dtype=np.float32)

        # Concatenate images and labels
        images = np.concatenate((tumor, healthy), axis=0)
        labels = np.concatenate((tumor_label, healthy_label), axis=0)
        self.images = images
        self.labels = labels

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        sample = {'image': self.images[index], 'label': self.labels[index]}
        return sample

    def __len__(self):
        return self.images.shape[0]

    def normalize(self):
        self.images = (self.images / 255.0).astype(np.float32)
```

Error Context:

```
model.eval()
outputs = []
y_true = []

with torch.no_grad():
    for sample in dataloader:
        for i in range(sample['image'].size(0)):
            image = sample['image'][i].squeeze().to(device).float()
            label = sample['label'][i].to(device)

            y_hat = model(image)
            outputs.append(y_hat.cpu().detach().numpy())
            y_true.append(label.cpu().detach().numpy())
```

I have tried every debugging method out there, printing and checking the shape[image: Debugging]

Comment: What is the shape you obtain for your tensors ? From the error you are showing, it seems clear that the shape of the input tensor is the problem: Input to a CNN must be batch_size,Channels,Dimension_1,Dimension_2. In your case, it should be 1,3,128,128.

Comment: Change `y_hat = model(image)` to `y_hat = model(image.view(image.shape[2], image.shape[0], image.shape[1]))`.

Comment: @AshwathS the shape I obtain from the tensor is [(5, 128, 128, 3])

Comment: @IshanJoshi The shape should be [5,3,128,128]. So, reshape it in that shape accordingly with tensor.permute(0,3,1,2) before feeding it into the network.

Answer (score 1):

According to [torch.nn.Conv2d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html), the input for the convolutional layer should be in the format **(N, C, H, W)** or **(C, H, W)**, commonly known as the channel-first mode. Therefore, it is necessary to permute (swap axes) from (N H W C) to (N C H W) or from (H W C) to (C H W).

```py
    # for (N C H W)
    image = sample['image'][i].squeeze().to(device).float()
    image = image.permute(0, 3, 1, 2) # (N H W C) -> (N C H W)
    # for (C H W)
    image = sample['image'][i].squeeze().to(device).float()
    image = image.permute(2, 0, 1) # (H W C) -> (C H W)
```